# Could this result in a memory leak?

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks

Consider the following two approaches of doing the same thing in jQuery:

```
// Approach 1
const $element = jQuery(...); 
$element.on('click', () => { 
    $element.addClass('ok');
});
```

```
// Approach 2
const $element = jQuery(...); 
$element.on('click', (evt) => { 
    const $element = jQuery(evt.currentTarget); 
    $element.addClass('ok');
});
```

If later on, somewhere else in the code, the `$element.remove()` is called, could any of these approaches result in a memory leak (or would any of these two approaches to be more likely in resulting a memory leak)?

If I understand correctly, the `$element.remove()` method, should also destroy the event listener on the element, and I presume that if the `destroy` is called, no memory-leak should occur.

On the other hand, what would happen, if no `remove` would be called, only the $element would be removed from the dom (by let's say, destroying one of it's parent elements and replacing it with another element)?

Comment: Can you link to the documentation of `destroy`? Plain jQuery does not have a method by that name.

Comment: Sorry, it is `remove`, corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `.html`, `.empty` or `.remove` to "destroy" elements, jQuery will internally remove all data and event listeners to the element and its children to prevent such memory leak.

As written in the docs:

https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

https://api.jquery.com/remove/

https://api.jquery.com/empty/